# Multiple messages in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, background, messaging, content-script

Let me explain the problem.
I'm developping a chrome extension and I'm stuck with a little functionnality.
I need to grab the url in the browser and retrieve something from my server to update the badgeText.

contentscript1.js

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({method:"sendUrlInBrowser",urlinbrowser: location.href}, function(response) { });
```

contentscript2.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getInfosUser"}, function(response) {
var url = location.href;
var id_user = response.id_user;
var default_friend_view_user = response.default_friend_view_user;

$.post("http://host/getNoteCount",
    {
        "url_note" : url

    },
    function (data)
    {
        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
        var note_count = obj[0].note_count;
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({method:"sendNoteCount",note_count: not_count}, function(response) {

         });
    }
); });
```

background.js

```
var urlinbrowser = "";var note_count = "";chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {if(request.method== 'sendUrlInBrowser') urlinbrowser = request.urlinbrowser;else if(request.method== 'sendNoteCount') 
{
    note_count = request.note_count;
    console.log(note_count);
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:""+note_count});
} });chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "getInfosUser")
{
    var storage = chrome.storage.local;

    var items_to_retrieve = ['id_user','default_friend_view_user'];

    storage.get(items_to_retrieve, function(items) {
      var id_user = items.id_user;
      var default_friend_view_user = items.default_friend_view_user;

        if(items.id_user.replace(' ','')!='undefined') 
        {
            sendResponse({id_user: id_user,default_friend_view_user: default_friend_view_user});
        }
    });

 }
else
  sendResponse({}); // snub them.});
```

The main problem actually is that I need to send the result of the cross-site request back to the background, so it has to listen to these two messages (url + result)
And I definitely can't :(
I'm quite sure I don't have to use connect() but if it does the work...
And I'm not even sure that I need 2 content-scripts.
Does anyone have any idea ? Thanks...

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Apart from the fact that you can use the single listener for all message types, all looks workable.

Comment: I don't have anything in note_count... It's always an empty string...

Comment: Why do you mix Requests (pre Chrome-20) and Messages (Chrome-20+)?

Comment: Hmm, good question, different examples grabbed from the Internet. Message is better, no ? And, I did find the error : {method:"sendNoteCount",note_count: not_count} I forgot a damn E in "not_count" Thanks anyway for reading :)

Comment: Also you have a typo: {method:"sendNoteCount",note_count: not_count}. not_count is not defined.

Comment: Yess, been looking at this script for too long I guess. What do you recommand as for Message and Request ?

Comment: In latest versions you should use Messages.